# Infix to Postfix

Tags: logic, boolean-algebra

4 + x / b - a + 5 AND x AND y OR p OR q

What is the tree and the postfix of the expression above?

I find it tricky because I am not sure if AND has higher precedence than the arithmetic operators, maybe OR does.

EDIT: I didn't realize that depending on the context AND could have lower precedence than multiplication for example. So lets assume that this is a code in Java.

```
if(4 + x / b - a + 5 AND x AND y OR p OR q)
```

How does this expression look like in post order to the computer? 
If I am not mistaken this would mean that the order of operations is

```
* / 
+ -
AND
OR
```

Someone correct me if you know better. If that order above is correct then the answer is:
$$4xb/+ a - 5 + x AND y AND p OR q OR$$

or

$$xb/4+a-5+xANDyANDpqOROR$$

Both should yield the same result, it is just a matter of how you write it, I think.

Comment: You have to know what you're not sure about before you can answer the question. The precedence assignment for this set of operators is not universal. Some compilers take AND and OR before + and -, some don't.

Comment: Lets say you are doing it by hand. How would you do it? Would you group 5 AND x or would you do everything on the left then AND?

Comment: I would go back to whoever asked this question and ask about their preferred precedence assignment.

Comment: But I made it up. So I kinda shot myself in the foot.

Comment: What if we say that it is an expression written in Java, would that allow a clear way to evaluate it? If yes then what would the post order look like?

Comment: The infix string is ambiguous.  Both postfix formulas you've written aren't.  I don't see any reason that when you're translating from infix to postfix (or prefix) you should always get the exact same result... unless the infix formula is not ambiguous by some conventions described by the author already, or some conventions taken for granted by some majority.  Consider two non-associative operations %, $ and an infix string x%y&z.  Is that xy%z& or xyz&%?  Equivalently, consider two operations X and Y.  Is the string xXyYz in postfix xyXzY or xyzYX?  Well, neither.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the hierarchy that you think is correct for Java and left-to-right evaluation within a level, your expression becomes

$$\left[\left(\left[\left(\bigg[\left(\Big[4+(x/b)\Big]-a\right)+5\bigg]\text{ AND }x\right)\text{ AND }y\right]\text{ OR }p\right)\text{ OR }q\right]$$

when fully parenthesized. The associated tree:

```
                                                              OR  
                                                            /    \  
                                                         OR        q  
                                                       /    \  
                                                    AND       p  
                                                  /     \  
                                               AND        y  
                                             /     \  
                                           +         x  
                                         /   \  
                                       -       5  
                                     /   \  
                                   +       a  
                                 /   \  
                               4       ÷  
                                     /   \  
                                   x       b
```

And you can read off the postfix string as:

```
                    4 x b / + a - 5 + x AND y AND p OR q OR
```

Comment: The postfix string here has one AND, while Mike John's string has two ANDs.

Comment: @Doug: That’s true of the whole answer: if you check, you’ll see that I inadvertently dropped `AND x` at the beginning. Fixed.